# Show Spacemacs keybinding window somewhere else (i.e. not in the bottom)

Tags: spacemacs

I was wondering if there's a way to show Spacemacs' keybinding window (when you press `SPC`) somewhere else other than in the bottom?

It might be a super obvious solution, but I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes,phss,it is a super obvious solution,the pop-up window you see  is which-key window,and in you `.spacemacs` file,there is a statement `dotspacemacs-which-key-position 'bottom`,you can just change bottom to right,then you can see keybinding window in your right.hope this could help you out

Comment: Thanks @samray, that was exactly it. A bit sad the options are only bottom or right, but at least I know where to look for now.